# How do max and min function work?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have below dictionary:

```
d = {1: 'zz', 2: 'we', 'as': 'dfda', 'x': 'zyz'}
```

And `max` and `min` return following:

```
max(d)
'x'

min(d)
1
```

How do `max` and `min` really work in this case?

Comment: Could you clarify what you're asking? Have you looked at e.g. `sorted(d)`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int

Comment: It should be noted that this would produce a TypeError in python 3 as python 3 considers there to be no natural ordering between ints and strings.

Answer (score 2):

`max` and `min` work on iterables. If you try to convert a dictionary into an iterable, you get back its keys. So, `max(d)` is sort of the same as `max(1,2,'as','x')`. There are some details on the ordering of the various builtin types [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons). As an example, `1< "a"` is `True`. This is used to find the maximum of the list. Similarly for `min`. As a note, I wouldn't recommend doing something like this in production code.

Answer (score 1):

`min` and `max` functions, when applied on dictionaries, they work on the keys of the dictionary.

In your case, they have to work on

```
[1, 2, 'as', 'x']
```

As you can see, there are multiple types of data present in it. [In Python 2.7, if the types are different, then the string value of the types are used for comparison.](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types). Quoting from that section,

> Note that comparing objects of different types is legal. The outcome is deterministic but arbitrary: **the types are ordered by their name**. Thus, a list is always smaller than a string, a string is always smaller than a tuple, etc. (The rules for comparing objects of different types should not be relied upon; they may change in a future version of the language.)

So if you actually sort the dictionary keys,

```
>>> sorted(d)
[1, 2, 'as', 'x']
```

As you can see now, the smallest is `1` and the biggest is `x`.